# How to delete space and value from col1 and create create new column based on it in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have table in Teradata SQL like below:

```
col1
-------
123 ABC Berlin
44567 ABC Rome
11 ABC New York
```

And based on "col1" I need to delete one space and "ABC" from column "col1" and stay only number, space and name of city, so as a result I need something like below:

```
col1                col2
--------------------------------
123 ABC Berlin   | 123 Berlin
44567 ABC Rome   | 44567 Rome
11 ABC New York  | 11 New York
```

How can I do that in Teradata SQL ?
I have code like that, but it delete both number and "ABC" what is not good in terms of my requirements: `REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '[^ ]+ ', '')`

Comment: If ABC is a fixed value it's a simple: `RegExp_Replace(col1, ' ABC', '')`

Comment: Are you really trying to replace the exact string 'ABC'?  Or are you trying to replace the second "word"?  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 0):

If the input pattern is **always** in the form of:

integer, space, word(no space), space, anything

then you could use:

```
select RegExp_Replace('11 ABC New York', '(\d+) [^\s]+( .+)','\1\2')
```

I substituted your col1 with a string literal to demonstrate.

The groups within () are called the capture groups, and they can be referred to by the 'replace with' part using `\#` notation (**#** being the capture group number, starting with 1 for the leftmost group).